# Default values of a const array (when not all indices are explicitly set)?

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I've searched around and haven't found an answer to this.  What I would like to know is this:

If I declare a `static unsigned char const ARRAY[256] = { [0] = <some_value> };`,
can I expect the unspecified elements (in this case all but the element at index `0`) to have a certain value, or will they be random?

I need this for a constant lookup table that won't have all elements filled, but isn't too large, so wasting some space isn't a problem.

Suggestions for more appropriate data types or conventions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest of the array will be initialized to zero.

Also, you may initialize more than one element in the array, for example:

```
char arr[10] = {1, 2, 3};
```

will create and initialize the array arr to:

```
index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
---------------------------------------------
value | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can go safely on my way. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be explicit about it and you're using gnu c, there's always `...`:

```
char array[256] = {[0 ... 255] = 0, [7] = 'f',/*and so on...*/};
```

Comment: No, there isn't *always* `...`.  That's a gcc-specific extension, not part of the language.

Comment: using a range for 0 is redundant, but for other values it might be useful.

Comment: I understand that it's redundant, but it clarifies intent. It shows that you rely on zero-initialized data. I use `malloc` then `memset` rather than just `calloc` for the same reason.

Answer (score -1):

If you want some particular behaviour, then initialize it that way.  Assuming some quirk of the compiler upon which the correct operation of your program is hinged is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Elements not specified in an initializer have a well defined value.